# Flask relacionamento de tabelas sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask

Eae pessoal! Venho pedir uma força, estou com um problema para realizar a contrução do objeto para criar o relacionamento das tabelas. Tenho uma tabela motorista e outra passageiro e uma outra ainda chamada corrida. 
Na tabela corrida preciso pegar um motorista e um passageiro, porem ta dando erro: 
NameError: name 'motorista' is not defined

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

#IMPORTAR FRAMEWORK FLASK
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship



#CONFIGURAÇÃO E CRIACAO DAS TABELAS DO BACO DE DADOS
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite3'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Motorista(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'motorista'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    nomeMotorista = db.Column(db.String)
    dtNascMotorista = db.Column(db.String)
    cpfMotorista = db.Column(db.Integer)
    modCarro = db.Column(db.String)
    status = db.Column(db.String)
    sexoMotorista = db.Column(db.String)
    corrida = db.relationship('Corrida', backref='motorista', lazy='dynamic')



class Passageiro(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'passageiro'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement = True, primary_key = True)
    nomePassageiro = db.Column(db.String)
    dtNascPassageiro = db.Column(db.String)
    cpfPassageiro = db.Column(db.Integer)
    sexoPassageiro = db.Column(db.String)
    corrida = db.relationship('Corrida', backref='passageiro', lazy='dynamic')

class Corrida(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'corrida'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement = True, primary_key = True)
    motorista_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('motorista.id'))
    passageiro_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('passageiro.id'))
    valorCorrida = db.Column(db.Integer)

db.create_all()

##REGISTRO DE CORRIDAS
@app.route('/registrarCorrida')
def registrarCorrida():
    return render_template('registroCorrida.html')

@app.route('/registroCorrida', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def registroCorrida():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        valorCorrida = request.form.get('valorCorrida')
        motorista_id = request.form.get('motorista_id')
        passageiro_id = request.form.get('passageiro_id')
        if valorCorrida and motorista_id and passageiro_id:
            corrida = Corrida(valorCorrida = valorCorrida,  motorista_id = motorista(motorista_id = motorista_id), passageiro_id = passageiro(passageiro_id = passageiro_id))
            db.session.add(corrida)
            db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
###############

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Substitua `motorista(motorista_id = motorista_id)` por `Motorista(motorista_id = motorista_id)`

Você deve chamar o construtor da forma como ele foi criado, no caso Motorista (com **M** maiúsculo)